# Get height of the safe area bottom inset from a keyboard extension

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

From a keyboard extension, we are trying to obtain the height of the space below the keyboard, when there is a home indicator. All the usual techniques are either inaccessible from the keyboard extension, or return `0`.

From the `UIInputViewController`, `view.safeAreaInsets.bottom` returns 0, as well as `parent!.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom`

And any method calling windows, UIApplication, etc. is not accessible from the extension.

Comment: did you ever use `AssistantKit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has confirmed that it is currently not possible to know the safe area insets from a keyboard extension.

Answer (score -1):

**If windows, UIApplication is accessible from the extension you can use the below methods**:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) 
{
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
let topPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.top
let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
}

if #available(iOS 13.0, *) 
{
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows[0]
let topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top
let bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
}
```

**If windows, UIApplication is not accessible from the extension you can use the below methods**:

Use the safeAreaLayoutGuide property. I have created the below extension, you can use it:

```
extension UIView {
   public var safeAreaFrame: CGRect {
     if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        return safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
     }
     return bounds
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
 let frame = self.view.safeAreaFrame
 print(frame)
```

Comment: Thank you; as mentioned in the question, not accessible from an extension